# Looking for an efficient way of finding the Covariance of Y/X and XY given a shared pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, covariance

I'm trying to do a past test's questions and one seems to be extremely computationally intensive so I was wandering how you'd approach it.
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) =\begin{cases} \frac{2e^{-2x}}{x} & 0 \leq y\leq x \\ 0 & \textsf{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Given $U=Y/X$ and $V=XY$ find $\textsf{CoV}(U,V)$ 
My thinking so far is either to replace $U,V$ with $X,Y$, open up the expression and compute it or use the 2×2 transformation formula to find $U,V$'s pdf and continue from there. I think it's doable either way but trying the transformation led to a nasty integral and the using X&Y way is computationally intensive- is this the nature of this question or is there a trick to ease the computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $X\sim\text{Gamma}(k=1,\theta=\frac{1}{2})$ and $Y\vert X \sim \text{Uniform}(0,X)$, so $E[X] = \frac{1}{2}$, $E[X^2] = \frac{1}{2}$, $E[Y|X] = \frac{1}{2}X$, and $E[Y^2\vert X] = \frac{1}{3}X^2$.

Using the tower rule, we get:

$$E[Y/X] = E[E[Y/X\vert X]] = E[E[Y|X]/X] = \frac{1}{2},$$

$$E[XY] = E[E[XY\vert X]] = E[XE[Y|X]] = \frac{1}{2}E[X^2] = \frac{1}{4},$$

and

$$E[Y^2] = E[E[Y^2\vert X]] = \frac{1}{3}E[X^2] = \frac{1}{6},$$

which gives

$$\text{Cov}(Y/X,XY) = E[Y^2] - E[Y/X]E[XY] = \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{24}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\operatorname{Cov}[U,V] = \operatorname{E}[UV] - \operatorname{E}[U]\operatorname{E}[V] = \operatorname{E}[Y^2] - \operatorname{E}[Y/X]\operatorname{E}[XY]. \tag{1}$$

Then for $a, b \in \mathbb Z$, with $b \ne -1$,
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[X^a Y^b] &= \int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{y=0}^x x^a y^b f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty 2x^{a-1} e^{-2x} \int_{y=0}^x y^b \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty 2x^{a-1} e^{-2x} \frac{x^{b+1}}{b+1} \, dx \\
&= \frac{2}{b+1} \int_{x=0}^\infty x^{a+b} e^{-2x} \, dx \\
&= \frac{2}{b+1} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(a+b+1)}{2^{a+b+1}}\int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{2^{a+b+1} x^{(a+b+1)-1} e^{-2x}}{\Gamma(a+b+1)} \, dx \\
&= \frac{(a+b)!}{(b+1) 2^{a+b}}. \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Here, we used the fact that the integral of a gamma density with shape parameter $a+b+1$ and rate $2$ is equal to $1$ over its support; thus we have the additional restriction that $a+b > -1$.  Since we are only interested in the cases $(a,b) \in \{(0,2), (-1,1), (1,1)\}$ for the covariance, there are no issues with convergence, and the rest of the computation is straightforward.

Comment: I think your method has a lot of merit, I'll review my knowledge of the gamma function and try it. Though I'm not giving you the "solve" because it was only discussed briefly in class and wasn't something we put a lot of emphasis into so I'm looking for something that uses our toolset

Comment: If you want to avoid the gamma function, you can evaluate  $\int_0^{\infty} x^{2}e^{-2x}dx$ using integration by parts.